# fuse (Filesystem in Userspace) error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, c, fuse

When I compile [this helloworld example](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html), I get the following error repeated 4 times:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

Here is the code:

```
static struct fuse_operations hello_oper = {
    .getattr    = hello_getattr,
    .readdir    = hello_readdir,
    .open   = hello_open,
    .read   = hello_read,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &hello_oper);
}
```

Comment: What C compiler are you using?  The error message looks like it's from gcc, but even gcc 2.8.1, released in 1998, supports designated initializers in its default mode.  I just tried and failed to compile that same example on my system (but I got different errors).  If you're using gcc, what does `gcc --version` say?  What OS are you using?  And what version of FUSE are you using?

Comment: My gcc version:gcc version 4.4.3 the FUSE I use is the newest version.

Comment: Please post your **entire** source, headers and all, as well as the compilation command. Please note that C and C++ are different languages, you can only use one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is too old. It needs to support C99. Pass in -std=c99 if the compiler is current enough

Comment: My gcc version:gcc version 4.4.3 the FUSE I use is the newest version. the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is using a new feature of the [C99 language standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) called *designated initializers*.  That feature is not part of the more common C89 standard (aka ANSI C), so a C89 compiler will give you syntax errors when you try to compile code that uses it.

To fix it, tell your compiler to use its C99 mode if it has one.  For example, if you're using GCC, you should pass the `-std=c99` compiler option.  If your compiler doesn't support C99 at all, you'll have to either switch to a compiler that does, or refactor the code to avoid using C99 features.

Comment: gcc supports designated initializers by default.  Even with `-std=c89 -pedantic`, it still recognizes the syntax and issues a warning.  Something else must be going on.

Comment: Yes, I tried to pass -std=c99 compiler option. but the error still exists

Comment: I add    #define FUSE_USE_VERSION  26                                in the beginning of hello.c and find that it compiles successfully this time. But anyway, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `gcc` support newer dialects of C (or of C++). Try passing it `gcc -std=c99 -Wall`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar error, although I was unable to overcome it by adding "#define FUSE_USE_VERSION ..." as mentioned in one of the comments above.

To overcome the error, I wrote a wrapper around the fuse_operations as follows:

```
struct my_operations: public fuse_operations {
   my_operations()
   {
        read = my_read;
        open = my_open;
   }
} operations;

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  return fuse_main(argc, argv, &operations, NULL);
}
```